# Django не передает username

Tags: python, django

Создании пользователя через **UserCreationForm**, не передается[image]

*Где только не искал ошибку нигде не нашел решение. Пожалуйста помогите.
Я даже перепроверял свой код и чужой и не нашел видимых отличий.
Пытался также на другой версии Django запускать код. Не помогает.*

Программа почему-то вместо username отправляет None, но пользователь регистрируется.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
views.py приложение users

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib import messages

def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        form.save()
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('usename')
            messages.success(request, f'Пользователь {username} был успешно создан!')
            return redirect('blog-home')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form,'title':'Регистрация пользователя'})
```

html шаблон

```
{% extends 'blog/main.html' %}
{% block main_section %}
<div class="form-section">
    <h2>Регистрация на сайте</h2>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type = 'submit' class='btn btn-outline-warning'>Зарегистрироваться</button>
    </form>


</div>
{% endblock main_section %}
```

urls.py основного приложения

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from users import views as UserViews

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('reg/', UserViews.register, name = 'reg'),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
```

main.html

```
{% if messages %}
  {% for mess in messages %}
  <div class="alert alert-success">
    {{ mess }}
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: "usename", может все таки "username"

Comment: да спасибо большое

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "usename", может все таки "username"

От пользователя  Iriskin.

Спасибо большое, буду решать проблемы с опечатками в коде чтобы больше не оставлять таких глупых вопросов.